# ASP.NET MVC View and Controller Output Caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller, outputcache

What is the difference between using output cache

in view:

> ```
>     <%@ Page Language="C#"
>     Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Mahmure.WebUI.ViewModels.NewsletterVM>" %>
>     <%@ OutputCache Duration="120" VaryByParam="none" %>
> ```

and in controller:

> ```
>     [OutputCache(Duration = 120, VaryByParam = "none")]
>     public ActionResult Index()
>     {
> ```

Comment: The difference is View-level caching vs Action-level caching. The former isn't currently cleanly supported in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC model it is more correct to use the attribute on your controller action because URLs are no longer dictated by views (as it is in classic WebForms) but from routing and it is the controller action that first gets the request and decides whether to fetch it from the cache or not.